# Re-hide hidden files?

Tags: windows, windows-10, hidden-file

Earlier today I was trying to view all of the hidden files on my C: drive. I found [this article](https://www.easeus.com/file-recovery/how-to-show-hidden-files-using-cmd-control-panel-and-software.html) and tried the first method they suggested, which was to enter `attrib -h -r -s /s /d G:\*.*` in the command prompt (I replaced G: with C:). Not having had much experience with using the command prompt, I assumed that this would give me a list of all hidden files, but I guess what it actually did was remove the Hidden, Read-only, and System attributes from all files in the C: drive with those attributes, so that now all files that were hidden are permanently visible. Is there any way to undo this, other than to manually reassign those attributes to all the files that should be hidden?

If it's relevant, I use Windows 10.

Comment: Unless you added ` > output.log` to the end, no. You won't have a record of what was and was not assigned the mentioned attributes.

Comment: Advice: Don't run any command unless you fully understand what it does.

Answer (score 0):

If you type `attrib /?` in part it shows -

```
Displays or changes file attributes.

ATTRIB [+R | -R] [+A | -A] [+S | -S] [+H | -H] [+O | -O] [+I | -I] [+X | -X] [+P | -P] [+U | -U]
       [drive:][path][filename] [/S [/D]] [/L]

  +   Sets an attribute.
  -   Clears an attribute.

…


  /S  Processes matching files in the current folder
  and all subfolders.
  /D  Processes folders as well.
```

Now from a command prompt and a programs perspective it doesn't mean much. You just see things you don't normally see. Nothing stops working.

However Windows Explorer uses read only and/or system to tell it to read the desktop.ini for special folders or custom icons. You cannot change these attributes on folders in Windows Explorer as the tri-state checkboxes always show indeterminate.

So when a folder loses its specialness in Explorer you need to make the folder read only using the `attrib` command. You may also wish to make the desktop.ini hidden as well.